# Remove invalid entry from Windows 10 start menu

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

I download Eclipse and ran the installer - at some point in time this was created in my start menu, and I can not simply search for Eclipse to launch it.

[image]

The actual installer this references had been deleted, and I can not primary, nor secondary click on the entry. It does absolutely nothing.

I have made sure that nothing exists in either

> %AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu
>   C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu

Despite all attempts to even search the registry, I can not figure out where this is coming from.

How can I remove this entry from my start menu so that when I search for Eclipse, the real entry, Eclipse Jee Oxygen, is the one recommended?

Comment: Try deleting cortana search history...

Comment: Is it installed now? All installed apps listed here `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`